# Regex: Match string from set of characters, but need to have exactly X count of a specific character

Tags: regex

I have a very specific regex match and I can't seem to figure it out.

I need to find full strings matches for `/^[aple]+$/i` but MUST match **exactly two "p's" and exactly one of the other characters**.

Any other characters are not allowed. Case insensitive.

So, for example, these will successfully match:

```
Apple
ppleA
APPLE
apple
ppale
```

These would not match:

```
foo
appple
aple
bar
test
```

I've tried to set the explicit count of `p` using {brackets} but I think I have the syntax completely wrong. Such as: `/^([p]{2})([ale]{1}+$)/i` -- not working at all. This one `^(([a]{1})([p]{2})([l]{1})([e]{1}))+$` matches "apple" but it doesn't match "pplea"

Assume I can do this in two sets of matches, run it first to get the set of matches that may have any # of p's and then do a second run to test for exactly two, but there has got to be a one-liner?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You could use lookahead assertions `^(?=[ple]*a[ple]*$)(?=[ape]*l[ape]*$)(?=[apl]*e[apl]*$)[ale]*p[ale]*p[ale]*$` https://regex101.com/r/MNs8XB/1 or if the `pp` should be next to each other `^(?=[ple]*a[ple]*$)(?=[ape]*l[ape]*$)(?=[apl]*e[apl]*$)[ale]*pp[ale]*$` https://regex101.com/r/spAbaO/1

Comment: `[]` does not expect an array of values. The commas are meaningless unless you're actually trying to match a literal comma.

Comment: The regexp you provided has a problem in that you are mixing curly brackes and + (the `{1}+` part) for cardinlity. Fixing that will not match all the strings you need, but one step at a time!

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Thanks I'll rewrite and fix the post without commas

Comment: @Thefourthbird amazing thank you. I'll do some testing with this. Much appreciated.

Comment: I never remember (or find hard to read) how to do look ahead / behind in regexes, so here is a clunky but readable solution `grep("ppp+", grep("[pP]{2}", words, value = TRUE), invert = TRUE, value = TRUE)`. This looks for all words with 2 `p` (or `P`) characters, then omits words with more than two `p`s. The look ahead / behind is better in a way but this is an option.

Comment: can the `p`s be separated or are they expected to be consecutive.

Comment: @Thefourthbird You've solved my issue with the first one (the two p's don't need to be together). If you want to answer the question I'll mark it. I'm glad I asked since this was more complex than I thought it would be.

Comment: I addressed the `p`s in my updated answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this would work:

```perl
/^(?=.*a)(?=.*p.*p)(?=.*l)(?=.*e)[aple]{5}$/i
```

- `/^` - start the regex and use a start string anchor
- `(?=.*a)` - ensure that an `a` exists anywhere in the string
- `(?=.*p.*p)` - ensure that two `p`s exist anywhere in the string
- `(?=.*l)` - ensure that an `l` exists anywhere in the string
- `(?=.*e)` - ensure that an `e` exists anywhere in the string
- `[aple]{5}` - get 5 chars of `a`, `p`, `l`, or `e`
- `$` - end string anchor
- `/i` - case-insensitive modifier

https://regex101.com/r/DJlWAL/1/

You can ignore the `/gm` in the demo as they are used just for show with all the words at one time.

Comment: You may want to make this a case insensitive regex, as the OP has `APPLE` as being a desired match.

Comment: @steveb It is in the demo but I've added it to my example as well, thanks!

Comment: Understood. Folks who are new to regexes can benefit from this a bit more, so I think it helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can assert a single instance of `a` `l` and `e` by using a character class and optionally matching all allowed chars except the one that you want to assert, preventing unnecessary backtracking.

Then match 2 times a `p` char between optionally matching the other chars  (as they are already asserted for).

```php
^(?=[ple]*a[ple]*$)(?=[ape]*l[ape]*$)(?=[apl]*e[apl]*$)[ale]*p[ale]*p[ale]*$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?=[ple]*a[ple]*$)` Assert an a
- `(?=[ape]*l[ape]*$)` Assert an l
- `(?=[apl]*e[apl]*$)` Assert an e
- `[ale]*p[ale]*p[ale]*` Match 2 times a `p`
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MNs8XB/1)

Or a shorter version using a quantifier based of the answer of @[MonkeyZeus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65415203/5424988).

```php
^(?=[ple]*a)(?=[ape]*l)(?=[apl]*e)(?=[ale]*p[ale]*p)[aple]{5}$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QnDiJ8/1)

Comment: My account rep doesn't allow me to upvote this answer (I clicked it), however I think I need to accept @MonkeyZeus's answer as the accepted response since it's more readable and it was answered earlier. This DOES work and match properly though.

Comment: @RinoBino That is perfectly ok :-)

Comment: @RinoBino I upvoted your question so now you can upvote this answer :)

Answer (score 1):

`^(?=^[^a]*a[^a]*$)(?=^[^l]*l[^l]*$)(?=^[^e]*e[^e]*$)[aple]{5}$`

This works by restricting the number of `a`, `l`, and `e` characters to exactly 1 of each, and then restricting the overall string to exactly 5 characters to enforce 2 `p` characters.

You asked about regex, but in case it helps, an algorithmic version would be to sort the characters of `APPLE` and compare to the upper-cased version of your string sorted as above.